# Unable to find dllimport: The type could not found in Script#

Tags: script#

Compile returned error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'DLLImport' could not be found...I have aacorlib in my reference.  When I look at System.Runtime.InteropServices, I could not found DllImportAttribute.  It is referencing aacorlib.  How can I reference mscorlib to get to DLLImport?

Thanks in advance!!

using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

...
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]

Comment: You can't use DLLImport in Script# as it is simply a C# to Javascript compiler. What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

Nick mostly answered the question, but just to make sure this shows up as answered -

Could you explain your goal? That might help understand the question.

DllImport doesn't make sense in script# scenarios, where you're using c# to generate javascript, and native access isn't an option.